# How to get no of day remaining for password to expire with powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2012

I'd want to understand as how do we get no of days remaining before password expires. I've the following query but it results in a date or ain't the relevant one

```
get-aduser xyzuser -properties * | select-object @{Name = "Password expires in" ; e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.“msDS-U
serPasswordExpiryTimeComputed”)}}
```

Output:

```
Password expires in
-------------------------
12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM
```

This is not the correct output. Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to specify which property you would like, instead of the all wildcard (*):

```
get-aduser xyzuser -properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | select-object @{Name = "Password expires in" ; e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.“msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed”)}}
```

The datetime conversion you are doing in your select query is simply passing nothing to the datetime conversion so you are getting the epoch date (less your time zone).

Comment: Thanks!! Tim. What if I want the same for all the users in AD and for more than one property? In that case I'll need to use wildcard.

Comment: The 'Properties' parameter allows you to specify additional properties that are not in the default list, so you will still have the default list returned. For all additional properties you can supply a comma separated list. To get everyone in the domain use '-filter *': `get-aduser -filter * -properties msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed,otherTelephone`

Comment: Many Thanks!! Tim. You saved my day. Your advise works, thank you again.